# Getting access to request parameters when contentType is application/json

Tags: jquery, json, rest, grails

I'm using the following jQuery code to send my parameters to my Grails application:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<g:createLink controller="myController" action="save"/>',
    data: { name: 'erik' },
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with the request
    }
});
```

In my Grails app, I have the following action:

```
@Transactional
def save(Speaker speakerInstance) {
    if (speakerInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (speakerInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond speakerInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    speakerInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'speakerInstance.label', default: 'Speaker'), speakerInstance.id])
            redirect speakerInstance
        }
        '*' { respond speakerInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

However, the name of the speaker is not filled. If I remove the contentType, the code works, but ends up in the 'form' closure, and I'd like to end up in the '*' part.

I tried getting the name using `params.name`, using `request.JSON.name`, but nothing gets the parameter, but according to Chrome, the parameter is sent, and when I remove the contentType from the request, it works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to `stringify` your object in your post whith `application/json` contentType?

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'erik' }),
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried that, I'll try that this evening. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Manuel, it works, but it seems the 'respond speakerInstance, [status: CREATED]' now doesn't work: I get a 404 because the GSP view cannot be rendered, which of course it shouldn't: it should render JSON.

Comment: Grails normally uses content negotiation in order to determine the response content type, but you should be able to force respond format: ` '*' { respond speakerInstance, [status: CREATED, formats:['json']] }`.

Comment: It works, thanks! But this is weird, and not the way it's supposed to work, I think. Thanks for the help, at least I can continue, I'll debug this issue later. Thanks!